# iPad Landscape orientation lock in JavaScript

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)
>   [Force orientation on iPad - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217805/force-orientation-on-ipad-javascript)

I have created webpage which I want to show user in iPad only in landscape orientation. I mean when user rotate iPad verticly it should still show landscape 
Is there any way to do it using JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before: [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

Summary: You can't "lock" it, but you can specifically target it, but also get notified if the device is in Portrait mode and display a message to the user.