# Anyone know how to lock a website (HTML) to portrait orientation on iPhone with (HTML) meta tags, javascript, etc?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, metatag

Does anyone know how to either lock Mobile Safari's orientation to portrait, or to block landscape (via javascript or otherwise)?

In other words, I want the web page to remain in portrait mode regardless of the orientation of the device.

Comment: This link will help to fix this issue 
[link for solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Answer (score 2):

You cannot lock orientation in iPhone's Safari browser. You can only [detect it](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html#DETECT_IPHONE_ORIENTATION_CHANGES_IN_MY_WEB_APPLICATION) and make appropriate changes to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't, but...

Consider very carefully whether this is a good idea or not. Personally I'm more often annoyed by the autorotation than not, especially when browsing in bed and the like. **However**, this should really be the user's own choice. It also looks like the next revision of iPhone OS will contain a software orientation lock, so that the user can disable autorotation at will.

Comment: There a stations where rotation is inappropriate for the app and make it less usable, such as using the phone as a tilt controller.. This should be a developer option

Comment: @Anthony On a web page? I suppose it's possible, but then I think it falls under my "consider carefully", i.e. there are special cases where it might actually be appropriate, yes. I think for most of those cases we are probably talking about an actual native app and not a web app though.

Comment: I know this is what I want to do on one of my mobile safari apps, I have considered carefully, but it cannot be done, and my users will loose out because of it.