# Is it possible to prevent the "flipping" in an iPhone website via JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, rotation

I just don't want the site change orientation when iPhone change orientation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer for how to use CSS/JS to rotate the rendered display on orientation change. The idea is to capture the orientation event, and then force the display back to portrait/landscape.

[How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

Answer (score 6):

You can't prevent this via JavaScript, it's browser controlled...and really you'd be breaking the user's expectations of behavior if you *could* do this, which is hardly ever a good thing.

Also if you could, which orientation would the user be in? When they arrived on your site the phone could have been in either orientation.

Comment: If you're creating a game or extremely specific interface, you should be able to prevent rotation.

Comment: @Stefan - No, you shouldn't.  If you're after a very specific display like this then write a native application, the browser should be the shape the user wants it, *exactly* like a desktop behaves.  It's not *your* choice to make for the user.  Also, is there something actually *wrong* with my answer? If you disagree with what Apple lets you do that's fine, but it doesn't make my answer any less accurate, you can't do this.

Comment: No, you're wrong. The browser IS an application platform, whether your like it or not. As such, you should have control over interface locking, as well as probably other hardware specific features. That's why the HTML5 spec includes geolocation, among other things.

Web applications CAN act like native, also, if you install to homescreen. It's silly if you limit a web app built specifically for the iPhone in this way.

Comment: @Stefan - Geolocation again is a *user choice* they can choose to disable or enable the feature, your app can and should adapt.  I agree pages can act like native applications in many respects, but controlling screen orientation isn't one of them.  Also I don't believe my answer said the browser *wasn't* an application platform, I simply stated you can't do *this* in that platform...and you can't.  So again I ask, what was actually wrong with the answer?

Comment: Not only are you philosophically wrong, you're practically wrong.

Comment: I agree with Nick, it's a browser...sure it is an application platform, but as with all platforms, you have to determine whether that platforms limitations will fit your needs

Comment: See my answer. It's possible to keep a single orientation mode.

Comment: @Stefan - The answer in your link *doesn't prevent rotation*, it adapts to it, which is *exactly* what I've said you should do, adapt to the platform the limitations you're on.  I'm glad apple lets you apply different CSS in this case, but you're not actually *preventing or reversing* the rotation.

Comment: You used "adapting" to mean "working around limitations". This is a dumb hack to prevent behavior which should exist. Apple IS wrong to not provide this feature.

But hey, who needs copy/paste?

Comment: @Stefan - I think you're *greatly* widening the scope of the question to fit your argument "what features *should* apple have included?"  While that is a great discussion, it's not the question at hand.  Should other desktop browsers support this when I rotate my monitor 90 degrees the same way?  Why not?  When you go into "things this *should* do" that's a *very* deep rabbit hole, and doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: Agreed that at its core a browser is just a very sophisticated, interactive text reader. Praising it as an application platform has always irked me. A browser is still a passive consumption device that displays content. The content shouldn't have any power over the user or display device.