# How to Stop Rotation of Iphone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

How can i stop rotation of the Iphone because it messes with my CSS so i want to stop that rotation landscape is there anyway to do it in Javascript ?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't control this, because the user might have already been in landscape orientation before he came to your website. But I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to just comment like I'd like to, but here's another similar question with some helpful answers (it doesn't look like there's really a way to do this in JavaScript):  [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)