# Vaadin Touchkit / Web app - Lock mobile screen orientation

Tags: iphone, html, vaadin, vaadin-touchkit

I'm wondering if it's possible to lock the screen orientation for a mobile device when viewing a web site (particularly a vaadin touchkit app).

Answer (score 0):

No.
Vaadin follows the same rules as all web applications, and this question has been asked/answered quite a few times on StackOverflow. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298467/prevent-orientation-change-in-ios-safari) has a hack to compensate for the orientation, but it's definitely not ideal.