# PWA - Forcing orientation to landscape not working

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, progressive-web-apps

We have a PWA on an Ipad where the manifest file specificy indicates it should be run on landscape mode, however I can still rotate the screen on the app.

Here is my `manifest` file

```
  "name": "App",
  "short_name": "App",
  "theme_color": "rgba(33,150,243,0)",
  "background_color": "rgba(33,150,243,0)",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "prefer_related_application" : false,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

As you can see `"orientation": "landscape",` is set, but it is not behaving that way. Any idea how to force it in a PWA?

Comment: Perhaps iOS Safari hasn't support for orientation in manifest.json. Did you try on other browser?

Answer (score 5):

As of today April 2020, the latest iOS Safari (iOS 13) has only [partial support for manifest files](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-app-manifest).

And `orientation` [does not seem supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_manifest_orientation). It will work on Android though.

You could have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298467/prevent-orientation-change-in-ios-safari) for some details and workarounds.