# How can I write a javascript web app that doesn't rotate when viewed on mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, screen-rotation

I have a web-app [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/CMpUt/show) that uses the accelerometer on the iP(ad|od|hone) devices, and HTML5 canvas. Unfortunately, the experience of the app is rather ruined when the page rotates.

Is there any way I can prevent it from doing so? If not, how can I make the landscape version identical to the portrait one?

Comment: Could you use CSS media queries to adjust to the aspect ratio of the landscape orientation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application/3261959#3261959

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

You will see this script to your problem: http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/