# Disable monitorOrientation in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

How to disable `monitorOrientation` property in sencha touch globally?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by disable you mean prevent the orientation from changing then it cannot be done in a clean way (at least on the iPhone platform).

You could (possibly) investigate the idea of re-oritentating the display when the orientation changes as described [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?107773-Prevent-orientation), although I'm pretty sure iOS won't let you prevent it (you may have some luck with Android)

[This thread poses a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

Answer (score 4):

You can disable, block the orientation in portrait/ landscape or other using :

- For Android if you open with Eclipse: The AndroidManifest under your "Application Nodes" => Screen Orientation
- For all system (IOS, Android, BlackBerry, WebOS ... ) : You can do this using Phonegap : it let you  encapsule your app in a WebView using HTML5.
  You just have to create a config.xml like this : https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml
  and add this :  in the   balise.

Next, you just have to compile your app using http://build.phonegap.com . It's free, easy and fast to use.

Hope this help you ;)