# Override orientation shift on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, mobile

I'm sure the answer varies from platform to platform, but is there any way to override a phone's ability to switch from portrait to landscape when you turn the phone?  I've noticed apps doing this (eg. Instagram) but I'd like to implement this on a mobile version of website.

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: Might want to check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036167/how-can-i-fix-the-webpage-orientation-to-portrait-only-for-ipad-and-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently this is possible with the [`@viewport` css meta selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/orientation). So:

```
@viewport{
    orientation: landscape;
}
```

I have no idea how well supported this is nor, it seems, do Mozilla. I'd eat my hat if it works consistently!