# iPhone website not in Landscape mode

Tags: html, iphone, viewport, meta

I try to turn off the landscape mode on my website. I don't want the site to turn into landscape mode when I hold my phone in landscape mode. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to find the right Viewport for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I lock the orientation to portrait mode in a iPhone Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application)

Comment: I know, but isn't there a more simple solution to do this?

Comment: I think if there was, it would be there already.