# How to force a Website to be landscape not Portrait

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'am new to web designing and wanted to know if this is possible? what i'am trying to achieve here is, the website i'am currently doing is fluid and so, the website should automatically rotate it self to landscape when viewed on mobile. please help. thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly this is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Answer (score 0):

can you check any tutorial about Responsive Design

here is some useful tutorials

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/

https://tutsplus.com/?s=responsive+design&post_type=all

Answer (score 0):

I Think if you use percentages in container width this should help you maintain the view point of the device the user is using. Here is a website I found talking about this http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/