# [Phonegap]How to lock rotation in specific pages

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to achieve the ability to lock the device rotation at certain points in my application, for example menu navigation could be done in both portrait and landscape mode but game play would be only in landscape.

Is there anyway to achieve this currently with PhoneGap? Short of having to brute force detect rotation with jquery etc and counter rotate the page?

It would be nice if their is some api call to lock or unlock rotation.

PS. i am using iOS7 and phonegap 3

Comment: You might wanna take a look at these answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Comment: @khemry i did read this, but when use webkit-transform css property to rotate the whole page, I found that the virtual keyboard will not rotate....