# Locking the ipad portrait orientation with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, landscape, portrait

I have built up a site and it's homepage background is a big image.On ipad landscape view is fine but in portrait view is very bad.I want to lock ipad portrait orientation only for homepage and do not allow users to change the orientation of homepage.How can i do it with jquery or javascript?

Please help me with this issue.I have browsed a lot but invain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Comment: Thanks for link.I had already read this article.But I need to block generally ipad portrait orientation only for homepage.!

Comment: It says there is no way...