# Disable landscape or portrait orientation with CSS mobile query

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-phones

Is it possible to disable orientation on smart phones with CSS media query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to disable the orientation by design.

What you can do with CSS media query is to check the orientation and change your css accordingly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries