# How to lock the screen-rotation, i.e. it should not rotate to landscape even when I turn the device in ios and android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, rotation

I want to lock the screen rotation, i.e. it should not rotate to landscape from portrait, even when I turn the device in ios and android.

The device should always be in portrait mode.

Please help how to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

simply add **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** between every activity tags in your manifest

Comment: is there a way to lock or hack an iPhone's orientation to portrait in mobile ios and android using CSS, HTML, Javascript or a combination there of?

Answer (score 0):

iOS: In XCode you can go to your target and under Deployment Info uncheck everything except Portrait for device orientation.

In android: android:screenOrientation="portrait"  in the activity tag in the manifest file

Comment: We are not using any manifest file.Can that be done using CSS or JS file?or else where do i need to add this code?

Comment: what tools are you using to develop the app?

Comment: We are using drupal and have used bootstrap 3 framework to develop the site.So we are using media queries for the devices like iphone,ipad or any android mobiles.Is there any way around?Please help.

Comment: We cannot do anything using the settings u mentioned above for ios.Same goes with android.We have only options to achieve this using CSS or JS or viewport in meta tag.

Comment: Please tell me some way using CSS, HTML, Javascript or a combination there of.

Comment: For iOS you can find more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207034/3482000

For Android try to use the size of the view to get the orientation.

If the orientation is not portrait show a java script popup to the user change the orientation

Answer (score 0):

add android:screenOrientation="portrait" to manifest

Comment: manifest as in?We are using only CSS and JS file.Where to add this code?

Comment: every android application must have a manifest

Comment: It has to work in ios as well.Moreover ours is just a responsive site where we have this  requirement only for mobiles having ios or android.Is there any way using media queries or viewport in meta tag or javascript as this is a drupal based site.

Comment: Please tell me some way using CSS, HTML, Javascript or a combination there of.

Comment: so its not android or ios, its a web app...

Answer (score 0):

for android put this in onCreate of all you activities `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: is there a way to lock or hack an iPhone's orientation to portrait in mobile ios and android using CSS, HTML, Javascript or a combination there of?